# qrcode_gen in R

Tags: r, latex, qr-code, sweave

I am the function qrcode_gen in R to generate a qrcode. My objective is to generate a latex file using sweave, with a QRCode. But I cannot resize it.

```
qrcode_gen("YourString", softLimitFlag = FALSE, wColor = "White", bColor = "black")
```

Does someone know how to resize the image returned by the function qrcode_gen?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are anyway generating a latex file, you can let latex do the qrcode:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{qrcode}

\begin{document}

\qrcode[height=2cm]{YourString}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If by any reason you need to generate the string in running time inside the R-Sweave you may save the QR_Code in a PDF file and add the PDF into latex.

```
<<message=FALSE, warning= FALSE, results='asis', echo=FALSE>>=

library(ggplot2)

inputString <- paste0("YourString",variable)

ggsave(paste0("QrCode.pdf"), plot = qrcode_gen(inputString, softLimitFlag = FALSE, wColor = "White", bColor = "black"), width = 21, height = 13, units = "cm", dpi = 1700, device = "pdf")
@

\includegraphics[width=5cm]{QrCode.pdf}
```